Deploy NextJS cron on Vercel
I have set up a very basic vercel.json on my project.
{
    "crons": [
      {
        "path": "/api/cron",
        "schedule": "*/20 * * * *"
      }
    ]
}

But when running the deploy script:
DEPLOYMENT_URL=$(VERCEL_ORG_ID=$VERCEL_ORG_ID VERCEL_PROJECT_ID=$VERCEL_PROJECT_ID vercel --confirm --token $VERCEL_TOKEN)
vercel alias set $DEPLOYMENT_URL website.com -t $VERCEL_TOKEN --scope company

I have no cron added to my project, it should be because I am not running vercel --prod
Is there any way to not ignore the vercel.json file using this deploy method?
This may be related to my NextJS version 12.1.0 which is pretty old.
